# REST: Handling the 400 error for GET requests

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

I have a `GET` request url `entities\{id}`. Here RestController is expecting id in a `Long` format.
Test case says that if user passes an invalid `id`, controller should return a `HTTP-400 Bad Request` error. 
For example:
`/entities/21.0`, `/entities/xx` etc.

But before hitting the controller itself jersey is throwing a `HTTP-404` error.

RestController looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response getEntityById(@PathParam("id") Long id){}
```

Comment: The method itself is not annotated?

Comment: I had just put the method signature to show how it is reading id. Updating right now.

Comment: Could you please provide your context configuration along with the whole class body. Is that the only unreach endpoint? Can you reach other rest services I mean?

Comment: @tmarwen Yes. I can hit other urls in the controller class.

Comment: I believe @DwB beat me as I was going to suggest the annotation change to `@PathVariable`

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: This is not a great solution, but it is an functioning solution.

First: I believe @PathVariable is the correct annotation, not @PathParam (I'm reading the 3.2 spring reference).

1. Change the type of the id parameter to String
2. in the method do a Long.parseLong(id) and catch the NumberFormatException.
3. Return the desired error indication for the NumberFormatException.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same. Looking for a cleaner solution here. Try/catch in a controller class does not look good to me.